# Visual Studio пересобирает проект, если одна из зависимостей обновилась

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всё думал, отчего столько проектов всякий раз перестраиваются, хотя в последний раз я их менял давным-давно. Поглядел в лог:

> Project '<…>.Controls' is not up to date. Input file '<…>.tools.dll' is modified after output file ''.
>
> Project '<…>.Sharing' is not up to date. Input file '<…>.controls.dll' is modified after output file ''.
>
> Project '<…>' is not up to date. Input file '<…>.controls.dll' is modified after output file '<…>.pdb'.

Получается, при изменении одной строчки в любой из широко используемых библиотек VS пересобирает всё остальное. Есть ли в этом какой-то смысл помимо проверки на возможные ошибки (чего можно добиться и иначе)? Отключается ли подобное поведение на уровне VS или придётся колдовать с `touch`?

***UPD:** Собрал какое-то дурацкое решение с манипуляцией временами изменения файлов, можно будет держать включённым в периоды каких-нибудь очень частых перезапусков (отладки интерфейса, например), но не более того. Конечно, круто, что запускается практически мгновенно, но что-то мне подсказывает, что однажды это выйдет боком. :)*

Comment: Ну да, все зависимости надо пересобрать. Иначе ждите проблем.

Comment: @VladD, вообще да, логично. Спасибо. Удалить вопрос?

Comment: Ну, может, кто-то скажет что-то более полезное, пусть лучше повисит пока.

Comment: Если в проекте есть ссылки на другие проекты, то пересобираться они будут по двум причинам: 1. если проект был изменен. 2. Если отсутствуют скомпилированные сборки. В остальных случаях вложенные проекты не пересобираются

Comment: Изменение прототипа сторонней библиотеки и привет! Правильно студия делает, не надо отключать :-)